Get list of files from Google drive into google sheets based on date range using app scripts
Hello I am looking for a script to get list of files from google drive within a specific date range.
I have got a script on this site here:
List new files from a specific Drive folder and subfolders in Sheets
Credits for the code : User Tedinoz
Code
    function ListAllFilesandFolders() {
  
  // List all files - analyse dates in query/filter
  
  /* Adapted from Code written by @hubgit https://gist.github.com/hubgit/3755293
  Updated since DocsList is deprecated  https://ctrlq.org/code/19854-list-files-in-google-drive-folder
  */

  // List all files and sub-folders in a single folder on Google Drive
  // declare the folder name
  var foldername = "<<Enter your folder name>>";
  var sheetname = "<<Enter your output sheet name>>";
  // declare this sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    
  // clear any existing contents
  sheet.clear();
 
  // append a header row
  sheet.appendRow(["Folder","File Name", "Date Created","Date Last Updated", "Size", "URL", "ID", "Description", "Type"]);

  // getFoldersByName = Gets a collection of all folders in the user's Drive that have the given name.
  // folders is a "Folder Iterator" but there is only one unique folder name called, so it has only one value (next)
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var foldersnext = folders.next();
  
  // declare an array to push data into the spreadsheet
  var data = []; //individuals fields in records
  var newdata= []; // whole records

  // list files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
  var myfiles = foldersnext.getFiles();

  // loop through files in this folder
  while (myfiles.hasNext()) { //start loop through main folder
    var myfile = myfiles.next();   
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var fcreate = myfile.getDateCreated();
    var fdate = myfile.getLastUpdated(); 
    var fsize = myfile.getSize();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    var fid = myfile.getId();
    var fdesc = myfile.getDescription();
    var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();

    // Populate the array for this file
    data = [ 
      foldersnext,
      fname,
      fcreate,
      fdate,
      fsize,
      furl,
      fid,
      fdesc,
      ftype
    ];

    // push the record onto the array
    newdata.push(data);
   
  } // end while loop through main folder

  // Now get the subfolders
  // subfolders is a Folder Iterator
  var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();
  
  // now start a loop on the SubFolder list
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {// start loop of subfolders
    var subfolderdata = [];
    var mysubfolders = subfolders.next();
    var mysubfolder = mysubfolders.getName();    
    // Get the files
    // mysubfiles is a File Iterator
    var mysubfiles = mysubfolders.getFiles();
 
    // now start a loop on the files in the subfolder
    while (mysubfiles.hasNext()) { // start 'while' loop of files
      var smyfile = mysubfiles.next();
      var sfname =  smyfile.getName();
      var sfcreate =  smyfile.getDateCreated();
      var sfdate =  smyfile.getLastUpdated(); 
      var sfsize =  smyfile.getSize();
      var sfurl =  smyfile.getUrl();
      var sfid =  smyfile.getId();
      var sfdesc =  smyfile.getDescription();
      var sftype =  smyfile.getMimeType();
    
      subfolderdata = [ 
        (foldersnext+"/"+mysubfolder),
        sfname,
        sfcreate,
        sfdate,
        sfsize,
        sfurl,
        sfid,
        sfdesc,
        sftype
      ];
      
      newdata.push(subfolderdata);
    
   }// Completes while listing of the files in the sub-folder
  } // end loop in the sub-folders

  // get the number of records in the array
  var newdataLen = newdata.length;
  var outputrange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, newdataLen,9)
  outputrange.setValues(newdata);
  return;
} // end of function

The app script should only find new files that are added within a time span like, startDatevalue and endDatevalue
When I am trying to run the code the system gives the below error.
Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. ListFilesandFoldersDateComparison @ Codegs 33:
which is var foldersnext = folders.next();
Can someone please advise how to resolve this?

If you need help with a script, [edit] your question to include the script

Thanks added the code script.

The JavaScript statement in the question, var folders next = folders.next();, is intended to assign a JavaScript Object to a variable. It uses the DriveApp.FileInterator.next() method. The error message means that this method can no longer retrieve any elements.
The referred statement is likely included inside a JavaScript loop that, for some reason, doesn't stop in an "elegantly" manner. Using the JavaScript knowledge, you might fix this by fixing the loop and adding a try..catch. There is a chance that you might ignore the error.
It would be best if you looked at the code to review the context of the method; for this, you need to have a minimum understanding of what is Google Apps Script:
Google Apps Script is a service-as-platform encompassing multiple elements. One of them is the web application used to edit "scripts". Scripts are written using JavaScript that could make calls to Google Apps Script services to do things with Google apps like Sheets and Drive. Each of these apps is also service-as-platform. From JavaScript, you need to understand variable assignation, conditional operators and loops. This understanding should help you to fix the code and to be able be better at finding scripts and adapt them to your specific needs.

Thanks Rubén, let me go through some more app script concepts.
